# How can I set the class for a <dt> element in a Zend_Form?

Tags: php, css, zend-form, zend-decorators

I'm trying to set the width of the style for a group of < dt >  elements in a Zend_Form.
Is there a way to set a class for a dt element, so the end result would be something like this:

```
     <dt id="name-label" class="xyz" > // trying to add the 'class="xyz"
        <label class="required" for="name">Name:</label>
     </dt>

    <dd id="name-element">
        <input type="text" maxlength="255" size="30" value="" id="name" name="name">
    </dd>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution - i needed to wrap the dt,dd elements in a < dl > tag and set the class of the < dl > tag. then i set the css for the < dt > elements through the < dl > class, like so:

Sample element:

```
        $question = new Zend_Form_Element_TextArea('question'.$i);
        $question->setLabel('Question '.$i.':')
             ->setAttrib('rows', 10)->setAttrib('cols', 40)->setAttrib('class', 'richtexteditor')
             ->addFilter('StringTrim')
             ->addDecorator('HtmlTag', array('tag' =>  'dd','id'=> 'question'.$i.'-element',
                                             'style'=>'width:350px;max-height:202px;'
                                                )
                                 )
             ->addDecorator(array('dlTag'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' =>  'dl','class'=> 'xyz')) //added this line
             ->addDecorator('Errors', array('class'=>'custom-errors'))
             ->setOptions(array('onkeyup'=>'textCounter();',
                                'onkeydown'=>'textCounter();'
                                      )
                                );
```

Then, i added the following to my css file:

```
dl.xyz{
        margin: 0;
}
.xyz dt {
    width:97px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-left: -15px;

}
```

this achieves what i was aiming for all along - modifying certain dt elements' style while retaining a general/default  < dt >style for the entire form.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
<form id='ID_FOR_FORM' method="post" action="">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <dt><label for="your-name">Your Name:</label></dt>
            <dd><input type="text" size="40" id="your-name" value="" name="your-name" /></dd>
        </li>
        <li>
            <dd><input type="submit" type='button' value="Send" /></dd>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Then in your css you dont need any classes or id for child elements of that form, you can simply go something like this for that dt:

```
form#ID_FOR_FORM ul li dt{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

That is how i like to work with css, make good markup, and then i dont need classes or id's, just do what i did in this example. :)

Comment: hi, that still does not help me. that is how i am currently setting the width of the dt elements in the entire form.
however in a certain sub-section of the form, i need a different width. hence, my original question on how to set the style for a group of dt elements, not the entire form.
Thanks for your answer though, but it does not solve the problem.